# need to calculate the age based on birth and discharge date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL and working on one of the query to find patients age who are under 26 based on discharge date.  I've added this condition under select statement "datediff (YY, BIRTH_DATE, HOSP_DISCH_TIME) age".  Please let me know the syntax to get age under 26 in where clause.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to achieve your goal

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF(hour, BIRTH_DATE, GETDATE())/8766) < 26
```

Comment: @kkaur02 please accept my answer as the answer if it solved your problem. thanks